# Which MQTT server for > 1M connections

Tags: mqtt

With a budget of perhaps a few million to setup a MQTT server farm how would you do so?

It must have the following properties:

- Support for 4-5M connections across all data centers.
- 300k msg/s of around 1kb each
- Geographic redundancy
- Can't lose messages QOS1
- Each client will publish to a single topic but subscribe to their own unique topic.  This implies 4-5 million topics.

MQTT Server brokers can be found here:
https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/server-support#capabilities

However capabilities are usually not published.

Comment: What QoS are you going to use?

Comment: Can't lose messages sort of implies that it's going to have to be at lease QOS1

Comment: QOS1

Also I need to declare that each client will publish to a single topic but subscribe to their own unique topic.

Comment: Claims are easy to make, hard to prove. There are too many variables to verify. Make sure to test your setup.

Comment: I am one of the developers of EMQ x mqtt broker. We can achieve that JMeter can test performance very well. Here is a test step video https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1yp4y1S7zb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBM Messagesight appliance. Specifically designed for large scale IOT deployments such as connected cars:
http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/messagesight

Clustering IBM IoT MessageSight servers is possible with v2.0 which allows you to scale a single MessageHub to multiple servers, thus enabling >1M connections even.

Comment: One appliance can handle
• 1M Concurrent Connections
• 13M non-persistent msg/sec
• 400K persistent msg/sec

Looks like a good starting point.  Thanks.

Comment: A downvote without a comment for an accepted answer, care to explain why it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: Have you tried emqtt.io ? they shows 1M connection support

Comment: Again, any reason for a down vote on an accepted answer with no comment?

Comment: is it open source, or some community version?
 search & glance at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWMAJ_5.0.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/QuickStartGuide/qs00002_.html, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 13):

Although the Erlang powered VerneMQ MQTT broker is still quite new, there is nothing (besides RAM/CPU/IPs/Bandwidth) that should prevent you from opening that many connections.

http://verne.mq

make sure to set something similar to:

```
listener.max_connections = infinity
listener.nr_of_acceptors = 1000
erlang.max_ports = 10000000
erlang.process_limit = 10000000
```

in your `vernemq.conf`

disclaimer: I'am one of the devs of VerneMQ and happy to help you reach your 1M connections/server.

Comment: What machine configuration would be sufficient ?

Comment: @Andre, could you please answer the question about machine configuration? Cheers.

Comment: A large AWS EC2 instance is enough. We once run a test on a c3xlarge with the Amazon linux image. However don't expect a great message throughput as the network stack isn't optimized for handling that amount of TCP connections. The problem becomes clearly CPU bound.

Comment: Is this erlang.process_limit = 10000000 still valid configuration? 1.0.1 vernemq.conf doesn't have this listed.

Comment: @suresh sure. it's a hidden option.

Comment: I've tested VerneMQ in my master thesis and compared it to RabbitMQ, mosquitto and EMQ(TT). In general, VerneMQ seemed to be the most stable implementation in single and clustered environments and did most of the time provide the best performance. No, I'm not developer or something at Verne ;)

Comment: @FranzHuber23 can you give us a link to download your publication?

Comment: @[WiRa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6280369/wira): I cannot provide the complete publication because it contains sensitive material from the company I worked at. However, I can provide some of the results. I already added the feature comparison here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13hvf72qNwIMt8ELu0XVsheA55uoCWLTn and will add an Excel sheet soon, too.

Answer (score 8):

[HiveMQ](https://www.hivemq.com/downloads/) is a self hosted, java based Enterprise MQTT broker, specifically designed to support millions of concurrent connections.

The HiveMQ team has done a benchmark, connecting more than 10.000.000 concurrent MQTT clients to a HiveMQ broker cluster. To reach this number, accompanied with a decent performance, some configuration needed to be done on the operating system of the used machines.

Open files in */etc/security/limits.conf*:

```
hivemq  hard    nofile  1000000
hivemq  soft    nofile  1000000
root    hard    nofile  1000000
root    soft    nofile  1000000
```

TCP tweaking in */etc/sysctl.conf*

```
# This causes the kernel to actively send RST packets when a service is overloaded.
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30

# The maximum file handles that can be allocated.
fs.file-max = 5097152

# Enable fast recycling of waiting sockets.
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

# Allow to reuse waiting sockets for new connections when it is safe from protocol viewpoint.
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

# The default size of receive buffers used by sockets.
net.core.rmem_default = 524288

# The default size of send buffers used by sockets.
net.core.wmem_default = 524288

# The maximum size of received buffers used by sockets.
net.core.rmem_max = 67108864

# The maximum size of sent buffers used by sockets.
net.core.wmem_max = 67108864

# The size of the receive buffer for each TCP connection. (min, default, max)
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216

# The size of the sent buffer for each TCP connection. (min, default, max)
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
```

Details on the VMs used, the specific configurations needed on the OS side and detailed performance results can all be found in the [10 Million Benchmark Paper](https://www.hivemq.com/benchmark-10-million/)

Disclaimer: I am part of the HiveMQ Team.

Comment: It's polite to point out that you work for HiveMQ when recommending it ;-) (I'm guessing, based on location)

Answer (score 1):

[Akiro MQTT Broker](https://theakiro.com/) deals with this scale and is a very reliable and low latency broker which is available which is powered by Async IO.

Akiro can handle 10 Million connections with 12 brokers with commodity hardware, which is one of the best benchmarks for a MQTT broker today. Its also being used by major telecoms. Give it a shot. Thanks

P.S I am part of the Akiro team  :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need few million dollars to achieve this. Actually you do not need even tens of thousands - [flespi broker](https://flespi.com/mqtt-broker) in it's commercial version achieves all numbers that you (were) need, except **Geographic redundancy** at that moment of time. And not only achieves - it is being used with multiple similar loads each day, 24/7 with 99.98% uptime.

It is cloud based broker with private namespace, so even it's free version available for everybody capable of serving the traffic up to 200 MB/minute.

Comment: Please disclose any relation you have with flespi

Comment: I'm one of flespi developers and maintainers